# Getting compilation error on esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeArcView

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-license-manager

I am getting compilation error on esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeArcView

1. I have installed Arcgis 10.1 and authorized ArcEditor. I am not able to authorized ArcView.
2. I have not installed Runtime Engine.

Am I missing anything any suggestions.

Comment: It's amazing the difficulties a marketing decision can create.  At 10.1 they broke the rules and changed it to `esriLicenseProductCodeBasic`, so you'll need to change your code and recompile. See [10.1 doc](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//004200000023000000).

Comment: @KirkKuykendall, that is the actual answer, not a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

At 10.1 they broke the rules and changed name in the enumeration from `esriLicenseProductCodeArcView` to `esriLicenseProductCodeBasic`.  Even though it still has the same value (20), you won't be able to recompile legacy source code without modification for 10.1 (AFAIK).  See the documentation [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//004200000023000000).